# Please help me in this nested for loop unix

Tags: unix, for-loop, awk, grep, cat

```
for i in `ls -l`; do for j in `ls -l /abc`; do cat $j | grep $i;done;done;
```

I want to search for each filename in pwd with files in abc directory. Please help me in this.

Comment: The above one is not working :(

Comment: Never loop on the output of `ls` in shell, any time you write a shell loop just to parse text it's the wrong approach, you don't need cat with grep (UUOC), and always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind that requires them to be unquoted and fully understand all of the implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want:

```bash
for filename in * ; do
    grep -F -- "$filename" /abc/*
done
```

Note that, due to the nature of `grep`, this will not work properly if any of your filenames contain newlines. (Fortunately, that's quite rare; but it's something to keep in mind.)

Comment: Thanks.Thats fine.I want to use two for loops and redirect the output to a file for each file in pwd

Comment: @user2433165 This answer seems correct to me. If you want to over-complicate your life by creating arbitrary nested loops, that's a self-inflicted injury or a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be the right approach IF the files in your pwd cannot contain newlines in their names:

```
ls |
awk '
NR==FNR{ files[$0]; next }
{
    for (file in files) {
        if ( index($0,file) ) {
            print FILENAME, file
        }
    }
}
' - /abc/*
```

but, like your grep approach, it's error prone as a file named "the" would match a line containing "then", and it'd report the same match multiple times if it appeared multiple times in a target file. If any of that's an issue update your question to show some sample input and output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question.. but what about just using find?

`find abc -type f -name $filename` ..

Even if the above does not do exactly what you want (which is a bit unclear to me), using a nested `ls` is pretty crazy if you already have a method which is ment to do just that.

`man find` if you want to learn more about the find command.

To do more with the files you located, you can use the -exec flag to execute something for each found file.